# How to select a Algokey when [ UserSelect] column has any of row value is 1 otherwise switch to[ SytemSelect]column haivng row value is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Scenario,Product,AlgoKey,User Select,System Select columns, I have to select the algo key for each scenario, The first priority goes to user selected  otherwise system selected.

I have Shared my Inout & output result below, could you please help me how to write query for this.

| Scenario | Product | AlgoKey | User Select | SystemSelect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P101 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | P102 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | P101 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | P102 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | P101 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | P102 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | P101 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | P102 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

OutPut :

| Scenario | AlgoKey | Columnselected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | User |
| 2 | 1 | System |
| 3 | 1 | User |
| 4 | 2 | System |

Comment: then why for scenario 3 , system select has chosen?

Comment: By your explanation scenario 3 should be 1 which contradicts with your results.

Comment: Because there is no value for user select column and then we need system select.

Comment: So what does UserSelect=1 for ProductP101, 5th row down, mean?

Comment: User has choice to select only one algorithm in given 2 and system recommend one algorithm. Priority always goes to user selected one.

Comment: @user15488631 based on your logic , still for scenario 3 it should be user selected in your final result

Comment: Sorry @eshirvana i edited the question. Scenario 2 & 4 are system selected 1&3 are user  Selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can do it

```
select scenario , AlgoKey, case when Userselect = 1 then 'User' else 'System' end Columnselected 
from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by scenario,productkey order by userselect desc, systemselect desc) rn 
    from tableName
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is a question to you, this query produces what you showed us as desired output based on your sample data

Comment: Yes @eshirvana i agree with you. I didnt mention there wiwll be many products for samae scenario.
But thank you so much for helping me here